# Dataset Manipuation Using Spark Java API?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm new in Spark Java API.
I have a Dataset like this:Ds1

```
|  account|    Lib     |  amount1 |  amount2   |
+---------+------------+----------+-------------
| 222222  |            |          |            |
| 333333  |            |          |            |
| 888888  |            |          |            |
| 888888  |
```

I want to get this Dataset:Ds2

```
|  account|    Lib     |  amount1 |  amount2   |
+---------+------------+----------+-------------
| 222222  |            |          |            |
| 333333  |            |          |            |
| 888888  |            |          |            |
```

Can someOne please guides me with a Simple expression Using Spark Java API.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this questions just about dropping duplicates? Or should there be some more logic if i.e. `amount1` and/or `amount2` are filled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dataset check Date column order using Spark Java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952410/dataset-check-date-column-order-using-spark-java-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use dropduplicates method on top of ds1 dataset

Answer (score 1):

Dataset yourDS2 = yourDS1.dropDuplicates();

OR

Dataset yourDS2 = yourDS1.dropDuplicates("account");